# Clearest and most succinct way of wording this confusing instruction

Tags: syntactic-analysis

I need a clear and succinct, 1 or 2 sentence way of writing the following:

> Create 40 digital images of a set of black items on a white background
>   in varying canonical and arbitrary arrangements. For each set
>   numerosity 1-8, create 5 images.

And to clear up any confusion about what the above means - a longer way of writing the same:

> Create a total of 40 images of black items on a white background, in
>   varying canonical and arbitrary arrangements, such that there are 5
>   images of 1 item, 5 images of 2 items, 5 images of 3 items and so on
>   until there are 5 images of 8 items.

Any method of writing it that I have come up with has led to confusion when asking people if they know what I mean. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What's your reason for needing to keep it short? Do you need to conserve space?

Comment: @RaceYouAnytime It's for the wording of a step in a marked piece of work. There is a mark for keeping the steps short and succinct.

Comment: Are there 36 items total such that no item appears in two different sets or are there 8 items total and each set just introduces a new item?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "marked?"  Is that BrE for an assignment that will be graded, or is it an engineering term, or something else?

Comment: 5 x1=5, 5x2=10,5x3-15, 5x4=20, 5x5=25, 6x5=30,7x5=35, 8x5=40, total 180 items?  In 8 groups? So not clear to me what's wanted, and then there's canonical and arbitrary. Numerosity is the number in each set?  8 sets?

Comment: @RaceYouAnytime Yes, we do refer to work which will be assessed, and usually annotated, by a teacher or tutor as being a 'marked exercise'. If you told British students that the work was to be 'graded' most of them would have to think about what you meant if they understood you at all. Exercises and other work which is assessed by a computer are often referred to as 'computer marked'.

Comment: @BoldBen thank you, that's interesting, and I didn't realize the difference was so "exclusive," for lack of a better word.  In AmE I find "marked" as confusing as a BrE speaker would probably find "graded."  The computer bit is also informative.

Comment: Create 8 sets of 5 images each containing black items on a white background in varying canonical and arbitrary arrangements such that the first set consists of images of a single item, the second set, two items, and so on with the last set containing images of eight items.

Answer (score 1):

Best I can do in a single sentence is:

> Create 5 digital images of a single item, 5 images of 2 items, 5
>   images of 3 items continuing to 8 items where each image consists of
>   black items on a white background in varying canonical and arbitrary
>   arrangements, resulting in a total of 40 images.

Sometimes, multiple short sentences work better:

> Create 5 digital images each of a single item, of 2 items, of 3 items, and so
>   on up to 8 items.  Each item should be black on a white background in
>   various arrangements.  There should be a total of 40 images.

Hope this helps.